# Adding scientific notation to y-axis changes height of bars in matplotlib bar plot

Tags: matplotlib, bar-chart

I want to make a bar plot with scientific notation on the y-axis.

However, when I use
`plt.ticklabel_format(axis="y", style="scientific", scilimits=(0,0), useOffset = False, useMathText=True)`,
the height of my bar changes and thus are not true to the input parameters.

I really don't know why this is happening. Please see the two attached plots and code.

```
fig = plt.figure()
# with and without below line
plt.ticklabel_format(
    axis="y", 
    style="scientific", 
    scilimits=(0,0), 
    useOffset = False, 
    useMathText=True,
)
plt.bar(x=x, height = height)
plt.xlabel('Load case no.')
plt.ylabel('Damage [-]')

plt.grid(axis="y",linestyle='--')
plt.draw()
```

| Without scientific notation | With scientific notation |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Without scientific notation (defualt)] | [image: With scientific notation] |

Comment: Matplotlib 3.3.4 cannot replicate the issue

Comment: Could I ask you to try and increase your bar widths, to something like 10 (`plt.bar(x=x, height = height, width = 10)`), to see if maybe they're just too thin to properly render?

Comment: In addition to @dm2 try setting `linewidth=0` when you plot the bars.

Comment: @dm2: it was a rendering problem... By increasing the width to 10 the correct height is displayed. Thank you

Comment: @JensPT I suggest playing around with the width parameter to make sure bars are not too wide either (otherwise they might be stacked one on another, covering some data).

Comment: @dm2 yep I found that a width of 2 in fact is enough. I might give it 3-4 just to be sure if I have more load cases.